# A is twice as many as B usage

Tags: word-usage

As far as I know, A is twice as many as B is the same as Twice as many A as B.
Can I convert it into an uncountable form ? like the below.

The size of a room I saw is twice (or two times) as much as that of my room.
The size of a room I saw is twice (or two times) that of my room.
I have a half as much my room size as that of the room I saw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I hope this may help.

You don't need to repeat 'room'. (It's a bit boring hearing it twice!)
We usually say 'twice'; rarely 'two times'.

"The size of a room I saw was twice that of mine"
- is not quite right. You haven't told us you've seen a room, yet you start talking about its size. We CAN say, "The size of *the* room was twice that of mine", because you have already told us about seeing a room.

But these are all good:

> The room I saw was twice as big as mine.
>
> I saw a room that was twice as big as mine.
>
> My room is half the size of the one I saw.
>
> I have half as much space as the owner of that room I saw.

Comment: We don't _never_ say "two times." It's certainly not wrong and I hear it occasionally. I also find your last example to be awkwardly pedantic, invoking the owner of the other room to perfect the parallelism. I think "I have half as much space as (in) that room" is much more natural.

Comment: I came up with a few examples of when we DO use "two times", but deleted them as peripheral to the question. I'll edit my answer to say "rarely" and "in this context". // That last example is my attempt at rewriting the questioner's: "I have a half as much my room size as that of the room I saw." Your version (which leaves out "I saw") is poor English. *With* your equivocal '(in)' it suggests you used to be in that room: you had that space. *Without it* you are comparing yourself to a room: it has more space than you. That is precisely why I introduced an 'owner'.